# No ouput for MYSQL join query for printing table on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
require_once 'dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_POST['search1'])){
  if($_POST['search1']=="tour"){
    $query2 = $DBcon->query("select * from tourinfo inner join flight on tourinfo.fid = flight.fid inner join hotel on tourinfo.hid = hotel.hid");
    echo "<table>";
              echo "successful";
    while($row=$query2->fetch_array()){
      echo "
        <tr>
          <th>Tour ID</th>
          <th>Destination</th>
          <th>Tour Duration(Day)</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Flight ID</th>
          <th>Flight Duration(hours)</th>
          <th>Depart Time</th>
          <th>Airport</th>
          <th>Flight No</th>
          <th>Hotel ID</th>
          <th>Hotel Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>".$row[0]."</td>
          <td>".$row[1]."</td>
          <td>".$row[2]."</td>
          <td>".$row[3]."hours</td>
          <td>".$row[4]."</td>
          <td>".$row[8]."</td>
          <td>".$row[9]."</td>
          <td>".$row[10]."</td>
          <td>".$row[11]."</td>
          <td>".$row[13]."</td>
          <td>".$row[14]."</td>
        </tr> 
      ";
    }
  }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Here is my code for using join operation of MYSQL and printing the column in a table form. However, there is no output displayed no even a cell or anything?

The "successful message" did appear and **I have tested the sql statement to be valid (MySQL returns several rows as expected)**. So what is the problem here?

And I don't need all of the data selected from the database so the index of row isn't consecutive.

Comment: It is probably not fetching any data or the query has some error.

Comment: Because nothing is found?

Comment: if your using `inner join` then no match is found it will be not include in the row. use `left join` instead

Comment: Yes, the while loop should be the problem but i don't get why the fetching is having problem..

Comment: Just like I mentioned above, i HAVE TESTED THE SQL STATEMENT WHICH WILL RETURN WHAT I EXPECTED, but just not showing on the browser....

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm not sure that it will work :

```
    <?php
    require_once 'dbconnect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['search1'])){
      if($_POST['search1']=="tour"){
        $query2 = "SELECT * FROM tourinfo INNER JOIN flight ON tourinfo.fid = flight.fid INNER JOIN hotel ON tourinfo.hid = hotel.hid";
        echo "<table>";
          echo "successful";
        foreach ($DBcon->query($query2) as $row) {
          echo "
            <tr>
              <th>Tour ID</th>
              <th>Destination</th>
              <th>Tour Duration(Day)</th>
              <th>Price</th>
              <th>Flight ID</th>
              <th>Flight Duration(hours)</th>
              <th>Depart Time</th>
              <th>Airport</th>
              <th>Flight No</th>
              <th>Hotel ID</th>
              <th>Hotel Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>".$row[0]."</td>
              <td>".$row[1]."</td>
              <td>".$row[2]."</td>
              <td>".$row[3]."hours</td>
              <td>".$row[4]."</td>
              <td>".$row[8]."</td>
              <td>".$row[9]."</td>
              <td>".$row[10]."</td>
              <td>".$row[11]."</td>
              <td>".$row[13]."</td>
              <td>".$row[14]."</td>
            </tr> 
          ";
        }
      }
    }
    echo "</table>";
```